# How to compare and assign/sort multiple columns with bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, multiple-columns

unfortunately I could not find any post for my specific issue. Maybe I used the wrong strings for the search. Nevertheless, here is the problem:

I have a file with 3 columns. I would like to sort the columns in the following way:
This is my sorted list of the samples (AA, BB, CC, DD, EE)

```
gene1 gene2 gene3
AA    AA    AA
BB    CC    BB
EE    DD    CC
```

I would like to have a list like that.

```
gene1 gene2 gene3
AA    AA    AA
BB          BB
      CC    CC
      DD
EE
```

So the idea is that I can easily figure out which sample is available for all genes, for only one gene or a combination of genes. 
How can I do this with bash commands?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Is the list of genes (AA, BB, CC, DD, EE) known in advance?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I tried to use join and sort but the results did not match my desire. Actually I had no idea what I should google to solve the problem. I tried "bash sort multiple columns by the first columns", "assign strings of columns", "align multiple columns by string identity" (etc.). The threads I found did not match my issue.
The list of samples for each gene is known and the sample names are all the same and are sorted in the same way.

Comment: Are these sample names saved in a file in the order you desire?

Comment: I have one file in which the samples per gene are listed in each column (col1= all samples which are available for gene1, col2=all samples available for gene2, col3=all samples available for gene3). I also have one file per gene in which the samples are listed.

Comment: And yes, the sample names are ordered as I desire. I am not sure if this is necessary for solving the task, as I do not care about the order. 
The samples are ordered in the same way. It is just that some samples of the gene1 list does not exists in the gene2 list and so on. I just want it to be listed with "gaps" in each column where it is non-existent.

Comment: For two columns, this could be easily done with `comm`.

Comment: Well if the order does not matter you shouldn't have mentioned it :/ I posted an answer by the way, check it out and let me know if you have any questions about it

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
  (NR == 1) { 
    print;
  } 
  (NR > 1){
    g[$1] = g[$2] = g[$3] = 1; 
    g1[NR] = $1; 
    g2[NR] = $2; 
    g3[NR] = $3;
  } 
  END {
    i1 = i2 = i3 = 2;
    for (key in g) {
      print (g1[i1] == key ? g1[i1++] : "  ") "   ", 
        (g2[i2] == key ? g2[i2++] : "  ") "   ",
        (g3[i3] == key ? g3[i3++] : "  ") "   "
    }
  }' genes
```